# how to pass params as json in ajax call from ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, rest, sinatra

I am making ajax rest call from ruby and its going to python to do  rest call proccess. when i trying to call rest and passing params in json formate, i think its may not passing this as json data.
My ajax call is following:

```
get '/cnet' do
    temp="mynet"
    url = URI.parse('http://192.168.1.9:8080/v2.0/networks') 
    params = {'net_name'=>temp}.to_json
    resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, params)
    resp_text = resp.body
    puts resp_text    
    erb resp_text
end
```

Python code is following:

```
@app.route('/v2.0/networks',methods=['POST'])
def net_create():
    net_res=request.json
    print "======================="
    print net_res['net_name']
    print "======================="
    net_name=net_res['net_name']
```

when i am trying to read json data from python its giving following error:

```
File "/network-ui/neutron_plugin.py", line 226, in net_create
    net_name=net_res['net_name']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I don't know what is exactly happening.

I am following there link for ajax post call:
http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-ruby.html
http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-rest.html

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You posted Ruby code, but your question is about a Python error? Post the Python code.

Comment: thanks blender. Now you can see edited post with python code

Comment: `params` is a helper method in Sinatra, so it's best not to use it as a variable name too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass JSON to `Net::HTTP`. The method requires a simple ruby hash.

In fact, you send POST params - POST params are sent through the HTTP request body, they are not JSON or whatever, just simple strings. This is HTTP basics, so i suggest you [read a bit](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod) about how things work over this protocol, it will be a lot easier if you understand it.

Regarding the python side, I don't know much Python but if you really need JSON (which i doubt), you will have to somehow parse the params.

Comment: ya i have to pass as string instead of json. Thanks. Answer on following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466029/how-to-pass-data-in-json-format-to-do-an-ajax-post-call-in-ruby