# how to pass data in json format to do an ajax post call in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ajax, json

First of all, I am calling a javascript ajax function that will call to the ruby function that gets called when I go to the URL:

> /cnet

From there, I want to do another post call from ruby in which I want to pass json data. How do I pass json formatted data to do this call in ruby?

My javascript code is the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/cnet",
  type: "get",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: {netname:netname},
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

My ruby code is the following: Actually, I tried it in two different ways:

1.

```
get '/cnet' do  
  net_name=params[:netname]

  @toSend = {
    "net_name" => net_name
  }.to_json

  uri = URI.parse("http://192.168.1.9:8080/v2.0/networks")
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
  #https.use_ssl = true
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
  req['net_name'] = net_name
  req.body = "#{@toSend} "
  res = https.request(req)
  erb net_name
end
```

2.

```
get '/cnet' do  
  temp="mynet"
  url = URI.parse('http://192.168.1.9:8080/v2.0/networks') 
  params={'net_name'=>temp}
  resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, params)
  resp_text = resp.body
  print "======================================================================"
  puts resp_text    
  print "======================================================================"
  erb resp_text
end
```

How do I pass json data instead of a string?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Accepted. I like it. Thanks a lot carolclarinet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to send json as a string:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start('192.168.1.9', 8080) do |http|
  json = {net_name: 'mynet'}.to_json
  http.post('/v2.0/networks', json, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json') do |response|
    puts response
  end
end
```

Comment: you mean like `{'net_name' => 'mynet'}` ?